# How to get default value of type from class property without referring to type explicitly?

Tags: c#, default-value

I want to do something like this: `default(typeof(MyClass.MyProperty))` so that in the event that the type of `MyProperty` needs to change, my expression `default(typeof(MyClass.MyProperty))` remains correct.  I think TypeScript has infiltrated my brain, and I'm not sure this is possible in C#, at least not as simply as it is in TypeScript.  But, for example, if `MyProperty` is of one type, like `int`, and for whatever reason, it changes to `string` later, I'd want my `default` expression to remain true.  Is this overkill?  Should I just use `default(int)` and make a comment that hopefully someone later catches in the event they are changing the type of that property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#typeof-operator):

> `typeof`
> The argument to the `typeof` operator must be the name of a type or a type parameter

So exactly that is not possible.

Note that you don't need to specify type, you can use the [`default` literal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/default#default-literal):

```cs
MyClass mc = ...;
mc.MyProperty = default;
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, hopefully this helps someone else, but I feel this was a silly question.  But I just realized that the `default` keyword is available as a literal and I can just use `default` by itself rather than `default(T)`.  Looks like I get what I want with the `default` literal.